# Trouble getting django-chosen ChosenSelect widget to work

Tags: django, widget

I'm trying to set up a ModelForm in Django that will use the django-chosen ChosenSelect widget for one of the fields. I have installed django-chosen and this is the code I have:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        widgets = {
            'field': chosenwidgets.ChosenSelect(),
        }
```

However, the specifying the `widgets` has no effect and the form is outputted the same regardless of whether I define it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including the [form media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/) in your template?

The example template below assumes that your base template has blocks `extrastyle` and `extrahead` where you include CSS and scripts respectively, and that you have included jquery 1.4+ in your base template.

```
# my_template.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extrastyle %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ form.media.css }}
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ form.media.js }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post">
    <table>
    {{ form }}
    </table>  
    <p><input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Turne out I had forgotten to include jquery in my base. Thanks for the help!

Comment: guys, I happen to have the same problem.  I have both `chosen.css` and `chosen.jquery.min.js` in my base on top. The widgets are still the same old. What else could be the problem? If I apply it myself in inline-javascript `$(".chzn-select").chosen();` it works. so something must be with `django-chosen`. :(

Comment: Kave - you also need to include jquery.chosen.ready.js

I had the same problem and solved it by linking to the chosen.jquery.ready.js file. So I have:

    <link href="{% static 'css/chosen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/chosen.jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/chosen.jquery_ready.js' %}"></script>

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution with using chosen.js directly. I installed it with bower and then included it in my admin class Media:

```
class MyModelAdmin(LockableAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm # has phase_id field

    class Media:
        js = ('components/chosen_v1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js', 'admin_tools/js/chosen_admin.js')
        css = {'all': ('components/chosen_v1.1.0/chosen.min.css', 'admin_tools/css/chosen_admin.css')}
```

The additional chosen_admin.js and chosen_admin.css files contain my init script and css for making the select look more like django admin. Here are the contents:

chosen_admin.js:

```
/* Create own jquery namespace */
var django = {
    "jQuery": django.jQuery.noConflict(true)
};
var jQuery = django.jQuery;
var $=jQuery;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#id_phase_id').chosen();
});
```

chosen_admin.css (optional):

```
a.chosen-single {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: white;
    background-image: none;

}
a.chosen-single span{
    line-height: 18px !important;
}

.vTextField{
    width: 24em;
}

a.chosen-single, .chosen-container.chosen-container-single, .chosen-container-single.chosen-single{
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    background: white !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    height: 18px !important;
    padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

I got some insights [here](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/2011/12/13/chosenjs-in-the-django-admin/) and made corrections as needed. Also see [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Hope this helps :)